# plot multiple horizontal bar charts on a single figure with multiple axis

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bokeh

I am trying to create a market profile / volume profile chart like [this](https://www.marketcalls.in/market-profile/how-to-read-a-market-profile-chart.html) or [this](https://jumpstarttrading.b-cdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/Candlestick-Volume-Profile.png) in Bokeh (or anything else - plotly?). Basically, I want to make a plot with horizontal bar charts on it where 'bins' define edges of bars in a bar plot, 'amt' defines height of bars and 'time' is on the x axis.

In practice, I was looking to add around 50-150 of these bar plots to a single figure, and I've got the following example pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:01:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22085.286, 22088.925, closed='right'), 'amt': 8.013, 'buy_amt': 3.05, 'sell_amt': 4.963},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:01:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22088.925, 22092.55, closed='right'), 'amt': 11.579, 'buy_amt': 0.106, 'sell_amt': 11.473},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:01:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22092.55, 22096.175, closed='right'), 'amt': 0.678, 'buy_amt': 0.002, 'sell_amt': 0.676},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:01:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22096.175, 22099.8, closed='right'), 'amt': 5.72300, 'buy_amt': 1.44899, 'sell_amt': 4.274},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:02:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22071.686, 22076.3, closed='right'), 'amt': 14.968, 'buy_amt': 3.885, 'sell_amt': 11.08299},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:02:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22076.3, 22080.9, closed='right'), 'amt': 0.1440, 'buy_amt': 0.001, 'sell_amt': 0.14300},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:02:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22080.9, 22085.5, closed='right'), 'amt': 19.137, 'buy_amt': 4.259, 'sell_amt': 14.878},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:03:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22070.691, 22073.8, closed='right'), 'amt': 14.03099, 'buy_amt': 9.532, 'sell_amt': 4.499},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:03:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22076.9, 22080.0, closed='right'), 'amt': 5.91, 'buy_amt': 5.91, 'sell_amt': 0.0},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:04:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22079.984, 22083.975, closed='right'), 'amt': 0.776, 'buy_amt': 0.68, 'sell_amt': 0.096},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:04:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22083.975, 22087.95, closed='right'), 'amt': 6.27199, 'buy_amt': 5.067, 'sell_amt': 1.205},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:04:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22087.95, 22091.925, closed='right'), 'amt': 2.156, 'buy_amt': 0.47600, 'sell_amt': 1.6800},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:04:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22091.925, 22095.9, closed='right'), 'amt': 7.481, 'buy_amt': 4.755, 'sell_amt': 2.726},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:05:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22076.491, 22078.85, closed='right'), 'amt': 26.618, 'buy_amt': 0.3080, 'sell_amt': 26.31},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:05:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22081.2, 22083.55, closed='right'), 'amt': 0.196, 'buy_amt': 0.137, 'sell_amt': 0.059},
{'time': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-07 23:05:00'), 'bins': pd.Interval(22083.55, 22085.9, closed='right'), 'amt': 7.582, 'buy_amt': 3.691, 'sell_amt': 3.891}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['new_bins'] = df['bins'].apply(lambda x: x.right)
df.set_index(['time', 'new_bins'], inplace=True)
```

my idea was to add multiple bar plots on a figure for every unique time period on x axis but that was just creating a single bar plot starting on the left hand side, and so the example below doesn't work.

```py
def plot_cluster_graph(df):
    from bokeh.models import Range1d
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

    TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

    bin_describe = df['bins'].apply(lambda x: x.right).describe()
    y = (bin_describe.min(), bin_describe.max())
    x = (df.index.get_level_values('time').min(), df.index.get_level_values('time').max())

    p = figure(tools=TOOLS,
               width=1000,
               height=400,
               title="plot",
               x_axis_type="datetime",
               x_range=x,
               y_range=y,
               )
    # get largest amt values per cluster + 1 to act as separator between cluster locations
    max_amts = [df.loc[time]['amt'].max() for time in df.index.get_level_values('time').unique()]
    amt_range = sum(max_amts) + len(max_amts)

    p.extra_x_ranges['vol'] = Range1d(0, amt_range)

    past_amt = 0
    for time in list(df.index.get_level_values('time').unique()):
        left = round(past_amt, 3)
        right = [left+i for i in list(df.loc[time]['amt'])]

        p.hbar(y=list(df.loc[time].index),
               left=left,
               right=right,
               height=0.5)

        past_amt += (df.loc[time]['amt'].max()) + 1

    show(p)
```

Any suggestions on how I can create this plot in Bokeh or plotly or something similar in python?

Comment: You've set `left=0` so every single bar will start at 0. If you want "floating" bars you will need to set both `left` and `right` appropriately. E.g. if you are looping each "column" of bars at a given time, you probably want `left` to be whatever the starting time is for the bars in that column is.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @bigreddot, I've updated the code based on your suggestion but I am just getting an empty figure without bar plots.

Comment: You need to actually examine the data values. I printed `y`, `left` and `right` and `y` and `right` were lists of different lengths which is wrong out of the gate. The sequences for vectorized properties all must be the same length (each "row" is one glyph displayed on the plot)

Comment: Also the left and right values were very small numbers, e.g. 32.716. The units of a datetime axis are *milliseconds since epoch* (i.e. a timestamp) so this would put the bar in early 1970.

Comment: in the figure initialisation I got rid of these `x_axis_type, x_range, y_range` params and I mostly got the output that I was looking for, and I will add datetime x axis as a secondary axis. So your initial suggestion with `left=0` was spot on, thank you for that! Do you want to post it as an answer, so I can accept it?